# Toggle current element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div filled with 'card' elements:
[image: Home page filled with cards]

When I click on one, the descriptions for all of them are toggled using jQuery:
[image: cards with description displayed]

I've managed to make it so that once the descriptions appear, if you click on the card, only the **individual** cards description is toggled back while the rest remain:
[image]

How can I also make the descriptions **appear** for only the individual card being clicked, not all of them at the same time?

jQuery:

```
  $('.front .description, .front img').click(() => {
    $('.back').show('fade');
  })

  $('.back').click((e) => {
    $(e.currentTarget).hide('fade');
  })
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="../img/card.png" alt="magic the gathering playing card" />
    <div class="description">
      <p>Black Lotus</p>
      <p>£1000</p>
    </div>
    <button>Add to cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <p>
      Necessitatibus sint earum temporibus consequatur quasi cum magnam aut
      sequi voluptate natus perferendis, illo ipsum voluptatem, saepe modi,
      ullam omnis consectetur eos sed iure non. Voluptate, molestias.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not sure how to implement `e.currentTarget` in this context.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to find the [**`closest()`**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) *card*, then [**`find()`**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the specific `.back`

```
$('.front .description, .front img').click((e) => {
  $(e.target).closest('.card').find('.back').show('fade');
})
```

**OR:** You can use [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword with normal function syntax (not *arrow function*):

```
$('.front .description, .front img').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.card').find('.back').show('fade');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$('.front .description, .front img').click(() => {
    $(this).parents('.card:first').find('.back').show('fade'); // this line
  })

  $('.back').click((e) => {
    $(e.currentTarget).hide('fade');
  })
```

Comment: `$(this)` not `$('this')`